# Creating a function

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile

I'm having trouble with code that I got from jsfiddle. It is supposed detect if the user is looking at a site from a mobile device. If the user is coming from the mobile site, it will keep them on the fullsite. It seems the first two return statements need to be in a function. I'm not sure, or confident enough, to put the function in and the code work right. Thanks for your help.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/8KYC5/1/)

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
    return; // skip redirect
}
if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
    document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
    return; // skip redirect
}

(function(a, b) {
    if (/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|meego.+mobile|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) window.location = b
})
        (navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://exactmetrology.com/mobile/index.html');
```

Comment: The code works fine, I just changed my user agent to an iPhone and your page loaded. Just put it in a script tag at the top of your page.

Comment: UA sniffing. Much cool. Very fun. So awesome.

Comment: The first two lines check to see if the user specifically chose to view the full site (possibly by clicking on "full site" in the footer.) Once the cookie is set, the last part of the code wont run until the cookie is deleted or the cookie expires and the page is reloaded

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I think @Danny is correct that this code does not need to wait until the document is ready, so you could do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    // PLACE THE CODE HERE
})();
</script>
```

This not only puts the code in a `<script>` element, it wraps it in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

Preferably, you would put this `<script>` element inside the `<head>` element, and it doesn't look like it relies on any JavaScript libraries, so you could try placing it before those libraries are loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't he just place it in a script tag? I don't see a reason on why he should wait for the document to be ready when he is just doing a redirect.

Comment: @Danny - That might be sufficient, but I'm not sure it is okay to have a `return` statement outside a function. Perhaps it could be wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).